# sqlite python: Как передать значение списком?

Tags: python, sqlite

Пытаюсь передать в SQLite таблицу значения из списка, для верного синтаксиса перевожу его в кортеж. Но все равно выдает ошибку Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

Значения внутри списка присваиваю.

```
async def sql_add_commands(a,b,c,d):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (?,?,?,?)', (a,b,c,d))
    base.commit()

file = []
    file2 = tuple(file)
    newfollowers = file2
    enemy = 'none'
    await sql_db.sql_add_commands(name,file2,newfollowers,enemy)
```

Comment: аргументы `file2` и `newfollowers` - кортежи, а в SQLite нет такого типа данных

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Функция принимает только два аргумента, а я таким образом отдам 5